# sinatra + angular.js + load template

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, sinatra

I'm using angular.js to get [this behaviour](http://angularjs.org/#wire-up-a-backend) in a simple sinatra app, angular works but it does not load my a.html and b.html templates. I also tried using `a.erb` and `views/a.html` in my main.js but it do nothing. What's wrong in it?

index.erb, a.html and b.html are in views folder.

app.rb

```
require 'sinatra'

class app < Sinatra::Base
    set :public, File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/static'
    get '/' do
        erb :index
    end
end
app.run!
```

index.erb

```
<span><a href="/">A</a></span> <span><a href="#/b">B</a></span>
```

main.js

```
var mymain = angular.module('main', ['ngRoute']);

mymain.config(
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
              templateUrl: 'a.html',
              controller: 'F1'
           })
         .when('/b', {
          templateUrl: 'b.html',
          controller: 'F2'
           })
         .otherwise({
              redirectTo:'/'
          });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given your `erb` templates any routes in your sinatra app. As a result, when you navigate to `hostname/a.html` then there is no available file. Remember angular is attempting to access `http://hostname/a.html` to get your html snippet, if sinatra doesn't know how to serve it then you're stuck.

```
get '/partials/:name' do
  erb params[:name].to_sym, layout: false
end
```

Try this. It will allow you to access your html snippets via your server address `/filename`. So to get your `a.html` snippet, with this route defined, you can access `http://server/a`.

Moving the files to your static folder will just mean sinatra automatically maps requests to the static folder location. Files that are statically served are preferred over any other routes you may map, and are usually pushed by your system default such as apache.

Comment: Moving files to static solder solves the problem but I was looking for a solution like this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved,

Just moved a.html and b.html to **static folder**.

I don't know if it is a bad practice or there's a better approach, If so feel free to comment.

Comment: You never gave your sinatra app any routes to your views. You have to explicitly route a request from `/a.html` to process your `a.erb` file in your `views` folder, it's not enough to just place them in the folder. All that does is make it available for compilation via it's name as a symbol- ie, `erb :a`. Until then angular is never going to be able to access those html template files.